# htaccess rewrite condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want a htaccess modrewrite rule to redirect my whole site to a new domain but except a folder. Such as, my site is www.mydomain.in and i want to redirect it www.mydomain.com but, if url is www.domain.com/new_folder then it should not to be redirect, stay on this site.

My htaccess is here

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/users/)$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.in$ [OR] 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.in$
   rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is not working. If i enter www.mydomain.in/users/ then it goes to www.mydomain.com/users/

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the right syntax.
Try it and reply me is it helpful or not....

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.in$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This was useful. Does anyone know why the order in the question doesn't work and the order in the answer does?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.in
RewriteCond !^(/users_folder)
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

if it doesn't work try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.in
RewriteCond !^(users_folder)
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

### Two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

May I ask you to add the rewrite log in your question?

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Not working and if i enter mydomain.in/myname.html then? I need to redirect my whole site except users folder and its containing sub folder